# What is this metal brushing sound from my car (audio clip inside)?

Tags: honda, noise, accord

I own a 2006 Honda Accord with 128k miles on it. Recently, I brought the car to the shop for an oil change, inspection (it passed), and transmission fluid replacement. A couple days later, I noticed this sound:

https://soundcloud.com/tfouad/car-noises/

It sounds like a metal brushing sound and it sounds as if its coming from the front/wheel area of my car. I hear the sound every time I drive my car, but only for the first few seconds of driving (e.g., when I'm backing out of my driveway or parking spot). After that, I won't hear the sound again for the rest of my drive.

What is it? Is it a problem that I need to get fixed immediately?

Comment: Sometimes a tiny stone can lodge between the disk (rotor) and the brake pad, which can cause an intermittent metallic screech like you say, which sounds much worse than the actual problem. This has happened to me several times on VW-derived cars, which can trap a small stone until it is released by chance, or by a mechanic loosening the caliper and retightening.

Comment: I'd jack up the car with transmission in neutral, turn the wheels and see if i can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mechanic diagnosed the issue and said it was caused by rust on the brake rotor. Since there is a lot life in the brake pads themselves, he suggested that I leave it alone until next time I get my brakes changed.